# Insert one large amount of data in one transaction

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, db2-luw

I have struggled with architectural problem.

I have table in DB2 v.9.7 database in which I need to insert ~250000 rows, with 13 columns each, in a single transaction. I especially need that this data would inserted as one unit of work.

Simple `insert into` and `executeBatch` give me:

> The transaction log for the database is full. SQL Code: -964, SQL State:     57011

I don't have rights to change the size of transaction log. So I need to resolve this problem on the developer's side.

My second thought was to use savepoint before all inserts then I found out that works only with current transaction so it doesn't help me.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to break this into smaller units of work.  The database is telling you that you can't have all of them in a single transaction.

Comment: Make an stored procedure with partial commit.

Comment: I know that i need to break it in parts. So i ask about any JDBC/DB2 driver trick  or maybe pattern that help.

Comment: @Zorglube what do you mean by "procedure with partial commit" ?

Comment: @megabobik you make an stored procedure witch make an commit for some chunk of 25000 line; that make 10 commit for your import.

Comment: You can do this with Java without a stored procedure.  Break it into smaller units of work and commit each batch until you're done.

Answer (score 2):

You want to perform a large insert as a single transaction, but don't have enough log space for such transaction and no permissions to increase it.

This means you need to break up your insert into multiple database transactions and manage higher level commit or rollback on the application side. There is not anything in the driver, either JDBC or CLI, to help with that, so you will have to write custom code to record all committed rows and manually delete them if you need to roll back.

Another alternative might be to use the `LOAD` command by means of the [`ADMIN_CMD()`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0023577.html) system stored procedure. `LOAD` requires less log space. However, for this to work you will need to write rows that you want to insert into a file on the database server or to a shared filesystem or drive accessible from the server.

Comment: +1 for the recommendation to use the admin tools.  Java's great, but it's not the best tool for every job.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use export/load commands to export/import  large tables, this should be very fast.The LOAD command should not be using the transaction log.You may have problem if your user have no privilege to write file on server filesystem.

```
call SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD('EXPORT TO /export/location/file.txt OF DEL MODIFIED BY   COLDEL0x09 DECPT, select  * from some_table ' )


call SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD('LOAD FROM /export/location/file.txt OF DEL MODIFIED BY COLDEL0x09 DECPT, KEEPBLANKS INSERT INTO other_table COPY NO');
```